# Should we include `.gradle` to repo?

Tags: gradle

I was using Maven for my projects previously. I just migrated to Gradle. The Gradle converter has created several files and directories under my maven project

```
        new file:   .gradle/***(many things under this dir)
        new file:   build.gradle
        new file:   gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
        new file:   gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
        new file:   gradlew
        new file:   gradlew.bat
        new file:   settings.gradle
```

Previously when I was using maven, I include `mvnw` and `.mvn` in my repo. I suppose `.gradle` is quite similar to `.mvn`. Should I include these files and directories in my repository as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:
You should add all of those files and directories unless the `.gradle` directory.

The best way to know which files and directories should we add to the repository is to understand what they are supposed to.

Inside the `build.gradle` file, you define all build-related stuff, like group name, artifact name, artifact version, internal and external dependencies, instructions to build and also publish the artifact, and so on. So we definitely need to add this file to the source control.

The main role of `settings.gradle` is to define all included submodules and to mark the directory root of a tree of modules, so you can only have one `settings.gradle` file in a multi-module project.

The `gradle-wrapper.jar` file contains code for downloading the Gradle distribution specified in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file. `gradle-wrapper.properties` contain Wrapper runtime properties, most importantly, the version of the Gradle distribution that is compatible with the current project. `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` are the Gradle startup script for Unix and Windows operations systems.

The `.gradle` directory includes a project-specific cache directory generated by Gradle. The content of this directory may frequently change by modifing the version of dependencies or the Gradle wrapper itself. So, adding this directory and its subdirectores to the repository and committing every change is not a good idea.

You can read more about the structure of a Gradle project inside Gradle's official documentation: [The Directories and Files Gradle Uses](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html)